# Random error: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: development, csom

I'm writing a C# Winform application with the help of CSOM library.
I need to navigate a SharePoint site and, when I point a PDF file. I need to download it and show it.
The basic routine (I found on the Net) I use to get files and folders is:

```
       private void GetFiles()
       {
            Uri fullUri = new Uri(currentPath);

            using (ClientContext rootCtx = new ClientContext(fullUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority))) //1. init context for root site
            {
                SecureString secureString = new SecureString();
                clientSecret.ToList().ForEach(secureString.AppendChar);
                rootCtx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(clientId, secureString);

                Uri webUri = Web.WebUrlFromPageUrlDirect(rootCtx, fullUri);  //2. resolve the proper web  
                using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
                {
                    SecureString secureString2 = new SecureString();
                    clientSecret.ToList().ForEach(secureString2.AppendChar);
                    ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(clientId, secureString2);

                    var list = ctx.Web.GetList(fullUri.AbsolutePath);       //3. get list where files reside
...
```

Sometimes the code runs correctly, sometimes it reports the error in the title.
How is it possible?

Is absolutely needed the call of SharePointOnlineCredentials() twice?

Why create two contexts? Maybe the first one is useless?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to following csom code to download a file from sharepoint

```
  ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://sp/sites/dev");
    Web web = clientContext.Web;
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File filetoDownload = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/dev/shared%20documents/mytest.txt");
    clientContext.Load(filetoDownload);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    var fileRef = filetoDownload.ServerRelativeUrl;
    var fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, fileRef);
    var fileName = Path.Combine("C:\\", (string)filetoDownload.Name);

    using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(fileName))
    {
        fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }
```